# Can't convert Yolo Saved Model to JSON Web Model

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I'm trying to develop a feature using Object Detection in a React Native app, I'm using YoloV8 to train the model. I trained and validated the model with my dataset, and tried with OpenCV locally, and it's working fine. However, now I exported with the Saved Model format, and then used `tensorflowjs_converter` to convert it into a web friendly model (JSON). But I receive the following:

`tensorflowjs_converter ^ More? --input_format=tf_saved_model  ^ More? --output_format=tfjs_graph_model ^ More? --signature_name=__saved_model_init_op ^ More? --saved_model_tags=serve ^ More? runs/detect/train/weights/best_saved_model ^ More? runs/detect/train/weights/web_model 2023-07-20 01:00:15.800876: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found 2023-07-20 01:00:15.801248: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine. 2023-07-20 01:00:18.788165: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found 2023-07-20 01:00:18.788893: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303) 2023-07-20 01:00:18.793356: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: Piersalvo      2023-07-20 01:00:18.794115: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: Piersalvo 2023-07-20 01:00:18.795266: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main     "__main__", mod_spec)   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code     exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\Scripts\tensorflowjs_converter.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 813, in pip_main     main([' '.join(sys.argv[1:])])   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 817, in main     convert(argv[0].split(' '))   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 804, in convert     weight_shard_size_bytes, metadata_map)   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\converter.py", line 533, in _dispatch_converter     metadata=metadata_map)   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 867, in convert_tf_saved_model     metadata=metadata,   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 680, in _convert_tf_saved_model     model = _load_model(saved_model_dir, saved_model_tags_list)   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflowjs\converters\tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 608, in _load_model     model = load(saved_model_dir, saved_model_tags)   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 938, in load     result = load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)["root"]   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 986, in load_internal     filters,   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 181, in __init__     self._restore_checkpoint()   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 527, in _restore_checkpoint     load_status = saver.restore(variables_path, self._checkpoint_options)   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 1481, in restore     self._graph_view.root   File "C:\Users\piers\miniconda3\envs\tf_python_6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 254, in restore     restore_ops = trackable._restore_from_checkpoint_position(self)  # pylint: disable=protected-access AttributeError: '_WrapperFunction' object has no attribute '_restore_from_checkpoint_position' WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_0 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_1 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_2 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_3 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_4 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_5 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_6 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_7 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_8 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_9 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_10 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_11 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_12 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_13 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_14 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_15 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_16 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_17 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_18 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_19 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_20 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_21 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_22 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_23 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_24 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_25 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_26 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_27 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_28 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_29 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_30 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_31 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_32 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_33 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_34 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_35 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_36 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_37 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_38 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_39 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_40 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_41 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_42 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_43 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_44 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_45 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_46 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_47 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_48 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_49 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_50 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_51 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_52 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_53 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_54 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_55 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_56 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_57 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_58 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_59 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_60 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_61 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_62 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_63 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_64 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_65 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_66 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_67 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_68 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_69 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_70 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_71 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_72 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_73 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_74 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_75 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_76 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_77 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_78 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_79 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_80 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_81 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_82 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_83 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_84 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_85 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_86 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_87 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_88 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_89 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_90 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_91 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_92 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_93 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_94 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_95 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_96 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_97 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_98 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_99 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_100 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_101 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_102 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_103 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_104 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_105 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_106 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_107 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_108 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_109 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_110 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_111 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_112 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_113 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_114 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_115 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_116 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_117 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_118 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_119 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_120 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_121 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_122 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_123 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_124 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_125 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_126 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_127 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_128 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_129 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_130 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_131 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_132 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_133 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_134 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_135 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_136 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_137 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_138 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_139 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_140 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_141 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_142 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_143 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_144 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_145 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_146 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_147 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_148 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_149 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_150 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_151 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_152 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_153 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_154 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_155 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_156 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_157 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_158 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_159 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_160 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_161 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_162 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_163 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_164 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_165 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_166 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_167 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_168 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_169 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_170 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_171 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_172 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_173 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_174 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_175 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).capture_176 WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).signatures WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.`

Not sure what to do at this point, I tried using `tensorflowjs_wizard` and I receive another error related to `signature_default`, which the model doesn't seem to have any. Am I even in the right direction?